# How can I retrieve the GitHub Actions workflow event logs and send it to AWS Cloudwatch?

Tags: github-actions, devops, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to capture the github action logs and send it to aws cloudwatch from github workflow

I have created the log stream like this:

```yaml
- name: Create log stream for cloudWatch
  run: |
    aws logs create-log-stream --log-group-name $Myloggroupname --log-stream-name ${{ github.run_id }}
```

and picked up the event log from one of the GitHub Action steps:

```yaml
- name: Retrieve terraform outputs
  id: tf_output
  run: |
    aws logs put-log-events --log-group-name $myloggroupname --log-stream-name ${{ github.run_id }} --log-events "[{\"timestamp\": $(date +%s%3N), \"message\": \"$GITHUB_WORKFLOW - Retrieving terraform output - $GITHUB_EVENT_NAME\"}]"
```

The above method I tried puts the log into aws cloudwatch. However, I have to manually enter the log message everywhere and would not be able to capture the failure logs either.

Is there a way I can retrieve the complete workflow log for the job and pass it as a message to --log-events?

Where can I fetch these complete GitHub logs?

Comment: See [Viewing logs with GitHub CLI](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/using-workflow-run-logs#viewing-logs-with-github-cli).

Comment: @Azeem Thanks for this, but it isn't the solution I am looking for. I want to retrieve workflow event logs, and show it up in cloudWatch.

Comment: With `gh run view RUN_ID --log` command, you can fetch the complete logs of a workflow and then send those to AWS Cloudwatch. Isn't it what you're looking for?